# Azure OpenAI AI Studio playground error - Completions call failed

Tags: azure-openai

We are getting error message "Completions call failed" in Azure AI Studio playground using GPT-3.5 when generate deployment and testing in Chat session.

Has anyone encountered the similar issue?

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8jBx.png)

Looking for a solution to resolve the issue posted.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the region that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Please test in the other region so that you will be able to identify the issue if it's related to the region.